# vtiger vs sugarcrm for building custom product

Tags: crm, rad, sugarcrm, vtiger

which one of those is better for building custom product? which one is easier and faster for development? i found vtiger to contains more modules but on the other hand sugarcrm seems to have better docs and easier in development. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the answer is still relevant. SugarCRM has its own quirks and unusual ways of doing some things, but is getting better organised with each version. vTiger, last time I looked at the code (a year ago) is still a disorganised hack-fest of thrown-together code. I would not personally touch the latter with a proverbial barge-pole.